# How to make an Assert.IsNull test pass when the value is reported as <null>?

Tags: unity, debugging, testing

I've just started using unity tests with the built in editor tests. After making my test and finding out that it constantly failed I debugged the code and found that a static object was set to a new game object when running the test while it is set to null when playing in the editor.

Is there a way to force unity to treat the test the in the same way that it treats scripts at run time?

**Edit**

After changing some code around i get another strange error:
[image: Editor Tests window showing error]

does anyone know why "null" isn't "null". The null objects are stored in an array, but that shouldn't make a difference right?

**Edit Edit (Edit 2?)**

Here is the code that has the issue

```
public class StatCollector : MonoBehaviour {

    public static StatCollector running;

    //ensure that there is only one object running at the same time
    public void Awake () {
        if(running == null)
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
            running = this;
        }
        else if(running != this)
        {
            DestroyImmediate(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the test:

```
[Test]
public void SingleTest()
{
    //create gameobjects
    GameObject[] collect = new GameObject[2];
    collect[0] = new GameObject("one");
    collect[1] = new GameObject("two");
    collect[0].AddComponent<StatCollector>();

    //see if gameobjects were created correctly
    if (collect[0] == null || collect[1] == null) Assert.Fail("failed to create game objects");

    //test what happens when the second stat collector is added to the scene
    collect[1].AddComponent<StatCollector>();
    collect[0].GetComponent<StatCollector>().Awake();
    collect[1].GetComponent<StatCollector>().Awake();
    Assert.IsNull(collect[1]);
}
```

I'm assuming that there is no way to keep Awake private which is why it is public (just so that the test case has access to it)

Comment: can you share your code for the test, it might make things easier

Comment: @DMGregory I think that could be the case but there are no frames in a test so how would one emulate that?

Comment: If you replace `Assert.IsNull(collect[1])` with `Assert.IsTrue(collect[1] == null)` do you get the same result? It's possible IsNull is using the standard comparison instead of the overridden one.

Comment: Yeah that solves it, post it as an answer so that I can choose it as an answer :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### First some background...

There are two flavours of "null" in Unity:

- Actual `null`
- "Pseudo-Null" - this is a non-null Unity object (usually
  a `GameObject` or `MonoBehaviour`) that has been removed from the scene using `Destroy` or unloading a scene.

  (In-editor, this is also used for reference fields in an Inspector that have been left blank)

  The reason this is called pseudo-null is that for an object in this state, `(destroyedObject == null)` evaluates to `true` using an [overloaded operator](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_eq.html).

Using `DestroyImmediate()` should put an object into this state immediately, while [using `Destroy()` will do so at the end of the current frame's updates but before rendering](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html), which can often help avoid order-of-execution bugs when multiple scripts are referencing an object.

The thing is that a "pseudo-null" reference isn't actually `null`, which you can confirm by calling:

```
System.Object.ReferenceEquals(destroyedObject, null); // returns false
```

...or by trying to access any of the object's members - you won't get a null reference exception, but a Unity `MissingReferenceException` (which is handy, because the debugging tools can tell you more about *which* object got destroyed while a script was still trying to use it - something we don't get from real nulls).

This psuedo-null stub will remain until all references to it are cleared/go out of scope, using normal C# garbage collection rules. [Read more about the reasons this exists in this Unity blog post](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/16/custom-operator-should-we-keep-it/).

---

### How this applies to your test

My guess is that `Assert.IsNull()` at the end of your test is internally checking for *real* `null` instead of comparing with the overloaded operator.

(Especially if you're using [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Assert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.isnull.aspx) rather than [Unity's version](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Assertions.Assert.IsNull.html) - I don't see any `using` statements in your code so I'm guessing)

Since the destroyed object is only *pseudo-null*, this check comes back false, tripping the assertion.

We can ensure it uses the overloaded operator to also detect pseudo-null by rephrasing the assert at the end of your test as:

```
Assert.IsTrue(collect[1] == null);
```

We know this `==` will return `true` for a Destroy()ed object, whether it's recently-destroyed or long-dead, so this phrasing reliably checks for what we want.