# Why is the while loop an infinite loop?

Tags: unity, c#

I do not know why this while loop is infinite, I've had to restart my computer about 15 times, trying to solve this problem.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;

public class CactusTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Animator anim;
    public EnemySpawner enemySpawner;
    public bool justToCheck;
    public GameObject AttackersHolder;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        enemySpawner = FindObjectOfType<EnemySpawner>();
        AttackersHolder = GameObject.Find("Attackers");
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        SetMyLaneSpawner();
        justToCheck = false;
    }




    void JustTo()
    {

        foreach (Transform child in AttackersHolder.transform)
        {
         //An infinite loop is going we need to fix it
            while (child != null)
            {
                if (justToCheck != true)
                {
                    justToCheck = true;
                }
            }

            justToCheck = false;

        }
        if (justToCheck)
        {
            anim.SetBool("underAttack", true);
        }
        else if(justToCheck)
        {
            anim.SetBool("underAttack", false);
        }
    }
    void Update()
    {
        JustTo();
    }
    void SetMyLaneSpawner()
    {
        EnemySpawner[] spawnerArray = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<EnemySpawner>();

        foreach (EnemySpawner spawn in spawnerArray)
        {
            if (spawn.transform.position.y == transform.position.y)
            {
                enemySpawner = spawn;
                return;
            }
        }
        Debug.LogError("Can't find spawner");
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to restart your computer. You can press Ctrl-Shift-Escape to bring up the task manager and kill Unity. [Alternatively you may be interested in this asset](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/40167).

Answer (score 5):

Lets step through this:

```
foreach (Transform child in AttackersHolder.transform)
```

`child` is automatically non-null, therefor `child != null` evaluates to true.

```
    while (true)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
```

Annnd that's infinite. There's no code inside that while loop that ever triggers a break, modifies `child` or otherwise gets out of the loop (return, goto, etc).

Comment: I used a foreach loop to loop through a transform with children. If those children are destroyed wouldn't it become null

Comment: @JaysonMeribe No. Destroyed objects are removed from the transform hierarchy. And even if your statement *was* true, simply *assuming* that *any* child is non-null produces this behavior.

Comment: Wait it so it's not null it's just not there

Comment: Yes, when a GO is destroyed, it's gone. It still needs to be garbage collected, but the way you're referencing things, it will never be null.

Comment: Note that `Destroy()`ed `GameObjects` will [compare as equal to null once the destruction takes effect, even though they're still valid, non-null references](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/129030/39518). Unity overrides the `==` operator for types descending from `UnityEngine.Object`. This does not impact this answer, but is a useful detail to consider when talking about comparing Unity types with null.

Comment: @DMGregory is correct. And the reason for this is because the destruction (the actual dtor and freeing of memory) does not occur immediately, but that the object should still be treated *as* null. Attempting to act on it (e.g. get a component, modify a value) will throw a custom Unity error, "The object has been destroyed but a script is still trying to reference it."