# Is `if (gameObject)` the same as `if (gameObject != null)`?

Tags: unity, c#

If you have a Game Object, and you want to check if it exists, is

```
if (gameObject) { }
```

the same as

```
if (gameObject != null) { }
```

and if not, what is actually being evaluated in the first statement?

Comment: See [Don't Use == null On Unity Objects](https://jacx.net/2015/11/20/dont-use-equals-null-on-unity-objects.html).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly more explicit test:

```
public class IfTest : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject toAssign;

    void TestIfs() {
        if (toAssign) {
            Debug.Log("if (gameObject) passes.");
        } else {
            Debug.Log("if (gameObject) fails.");
        }

        if (toAssign != null) {
            Debug.Log("if (gameObject != null) passes.");
        } else {
            Debug.Log("if (gameObject != null) fails.");
        }

        if (System.Object.ReferenceEquals(toAssign, null)) {
            Debug.Log("if (ReferenceEquals null) passes.");
        } else {
            Debug.Log("if (ReferenceEquals null) fails.");
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Start() {
        Debug.Log("-------Before assigning:----------");
        TestIfs();

        Debug.Log("-------Assigning:-----------------");
        toAssign = new GameObject();
        TestIfs(); 

        Debug.Log("-------Destroying:----------------");
        Destroy(toAssign);
        TestIfs();             

        // Wait one frame for the destruction to take effect.
        yield return null;
        Debug.Log("-------1 frame later:-------------");
        TestIfs();        

        Debug.Log("-------Unassigning:---------------");
        toAssign = null;
        TestIfs();                    
    }
}
```

Here's the output you get:

```
-------Before assigning:----------
if (gameObject) fails.
if (gameObject != null) fails.
if (!ReferenceEquals null) passes.
-------Assigning:-----------------
if (gameObject) passes.
if (gameObject != null) passes.
if (!ReferenceEquals null) passes.
-------Destroying:----------------
if (gameObject) passes.
if (gameObject != null) passes.
if (!ReferenceEquals null) passes.
-------1 frame later:-------------
if (gameObject) fails.
if (gameObject != null) fails.
if (!ReferenceEquals null) passes.
-------Unassigning:---------------
if (gameObject) fails.
if (gameObject != null) fails.
if (!ReferenceEquals null) fails.
```

So, the takeaways from this experiment that you can do yourself:

- `if (gameObject)` and `if (gameObject != null)` behave the same.
- Both will evaluate as `true` in the frame that their object is destroyed
- Both will evaluate as `false` starting the frame *after* their object is destroyed.
- `!Object.ReferenceEquals(gameObject, null)` will still evaluate as `true` on a destroyed object, because it's only been *marked* as invalid, [it's not literally a `null` value](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/129030/39518).
- In the Editor, `!Object.ReferenceEquals(gameObject, null)` will *also* evaluate as `true` on an unassigned object reference. The Editor inserts a special non-null placeholder object there secretly, so that it can give you better error messages if you try to use a reference you haven't assigned yet. But these placeholders still compare as equal to `null` with the other two methods, and aren't used at all in the built executable.
- All three behave the same for a value that is actually, literally a `null` - like one you assigned there by hand.

You can repeat this test for a component reference and get the same results.