# MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'CapsuleCollider' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it

Tags: unity

i use this code , but when the health is below to 0 and destroy the gameobject , unity show the error "MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'CapsuleCollider' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it."

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (canAttack && other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            canAttack = false;
            if(other != null)
            {
                StartCoroutine(AttackPlayer(other));
            }
        }
    }
    IEnumerator AttackPlayer(Collider playerCollider)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            playerCollider.GetComponent<Player>().TakeDamage(damageAmount);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        }
    }
```

and i alreally check the colider is null before.

here is the player script

```
public void TakeDamage(float damage)
    {
        Health -= damage;
        if (Health < 0)
        {
            Die();
        }
    }

    private void Die()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
```

i try to check is null still no work, no debug log

````
IEnumerator AttackPlayer(Collider playerCollider)
    {
        
        while (true)
        {
            if (playerCollider.gameObject == null)
            {
                Debug.Log("111");
                yield break; 
            }
            playerCollider.GetComponent<Player>().TakeDamage(damageAmount);
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(AttackSpeed);
        }
    }
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the player has been destroyed (eg. by taking lethal damage), then every component attached to the player will be [treated as](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/115761/39518) null, including the player collider.

Once the collider is being [treated as](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/129030/39518) null, trying to use the dot operator to access *anything* about the collider will throw an exception. That includes:

- `playerCollider.GetComponent<Player>()` - if `playerCollider` is `null`, then this is `null.GetComponent`, and `null` does not have a `getComponent` method --> exception!
- `playerCollider.gameObject == null` - if `playerCollider` is `null`, then this is `null.gameObject`, and `null` does not have a `gameObject` member --> exception!

So if you think something could have been destroyed, don't use the dot operator! Check it for null first!

A better version of this code would look like this:

```cs
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    // You know players have the Player component, so check for that, not a tag.
    if (canAttack && other.TryGetComponent(out Player player))
    {
        canAttack = false;
        // Now we can pass the player component itself to the attack function.
        StartCoroutine(AttackPlayer(player));
    }
}

IEnumerator AttackPlayer(Player player)
{
    // If the player is killed, STOP LOOPING.
    while (player != null)
    {
        // No more GetComponent() search in the middle of the loop.
        player.TakeDamage(damageAmount);

        // You could construct the wait once and cache it.
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
    }

    // My target is dead, I can try to attack a different target now.
    canAttack = true;
}
```