# How can I make sure that a component gets destroyed the last out of all components attached to an object in Unity?

Tags: unity

How can I make sure that a component gets destroyed the last out of all components attached to an object in Unity?

I have a component with some scripts on it: `Script1` and `Script2`. Inside the `Script2.OnDestroy` method I have the following line of code: `GetComponentInParent<Script1>()`.

I want that line of code to return `Script1` whenever I click the `Play` button inside Unity editor to stop my game. While right now it returns `null`.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Perhaps there is a better way to achieve your *actual* goal.

Comment: @Philipp, I am using the broker pattern. I have a few complex objects (and hence a few `Broker`s for each object) which consist of different parts. These parts communicate with each other through a broker. I retrieve a broker using the `GetComponentInParent<Broker>()`. Now in `OnDestroy` I need to unsubscribe from the `Broker`. So, I need the `Broker` component to get destroyed the last.

Comment: If the `Broker` is destroyed, why do you need to unsubscribe from it?

Comment: @Kevin, Because sometimes the broker does not get destroyed along with the parts. I may just destroy the part myself from script during gameplay. I thought about checking if broker is null, but it feels not a very neat approach, because it violates the fail fast principle and hence all the issues which may happen due to this.

Comment: @Kevin, also, I would not really care about checking for broker being null if Unity would not call the `OnDestroy` when I completely turn off the game. But since Unity does call it, I think it expects me to do all the cleanup. E.g. unsubscribe from broker.

Comment: In my mind, checking if `Broker` is null is a lot cleaner than trying to ensure components are destroyed in a specific order.

Comment: @Kevin, later on I may remove the broker accidentally or will forget to add it and my game will be broken without me even knowing about it. While the fail fast allows me to catch the problem easily.

Comment: Unity very rarely requires you to do any cleanups. What cleanups exactly do you need to perform when the game quits and why?

Comment: I don't _think_ you actually need to do any cleanup when the game stops, unless you need to save or have active file handles to close or something like that. I always write my `OnDestroys()` with null checks, e.g. `if (someObject != null) someObject.SomeEvent.RemoveListener(someListener)`. Which can be shortened to `someObject?.SomeEvent.RemoveListener(someListener)`

Comment: Ok. I will try to reasearch the matter a little more and will remove the question and use the null check if I will find no other alternative. Thank you both. :)

Comment: You may be interested in [In Unity, does a reference delegate clear out when its parent GameObject is destroyed?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/131059/39518)