# Lag in Destroy() method

Tags: unity

I have a script that destroys the player object when a collider with that script touches it. The thing is that, even if there is no time specified in the script, it takes couple seconds before it destroys the player. Why does this happen, and how do I get around it?

```
public class DestroyScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject player;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collision otherObj)
    {
        if (otherObj.gameObject.tag == "Player")
            Destroy(player);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's because `Destroy`  called on a `GameObject` will Invoke `Destroy` on each of the `Components` and `Object`s held by this `GameObject` try to make an `Coroutine` which will destroy `Component`s one by one instead of all at once.

Comment: Thanks. Anyway , I changed my code to :
`public class DestroyScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject player;
 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {
 
 }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider otherObj)
    { if(otherObj.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        Destroy(otherObj.gameObject);
    }
`

Comment: You cannot "destroy" an object in a managed environment. The most Unity can do is set the object to null, along with every child entity it owns. This leads me to believe that your design is fatally flawed, much as your understanding is of how Unity works. I'm downvoting for blatant lack of personal research,

Comment: @Krythic, the question specifically only asks about calling 'Destroy()' on the object. I think it is safe to assume that this functionality is the expected functionality when the asked reports "destroying the player". You can do this quite easily, in Unity. If your still confused, I can link some basic tutorials or examples that demonstrate this.

Comment: @Krythic, it appears to me that you may be the one who misunderstands Unity's workings. The GameObject that our managed C# scripts reference is actually a wrapper linking to a corresponding piece of data in unmanaged code. When Unity decides to delete that backing object, it can do so with impunity. [It then sets the managed GameObject into a special state where it compares as equal to null but is not actually null](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/115761/39518) (generating MissingReferenceExceptions when you try to use it), until all references to it are cleared/go out of scope as per usual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Destroy()` does not have an immediate affect on a `GameObject`. As *m.rogalski* points out, `Destroy()` ensures that the `GameObject` is destroyed *safely*. There are a couple of ways around this. If we want the `GameObject` to be immediately invisible to the game, we can use `SetActive()`. If we really need to, we can use `DestroyImmediate()`, though usage is unadvised.

#### Making the `GameObject` invisible as we `Destroy()` it

If you want the `GameObject` to be immediately invisible to the player, when you call `Destroy()`, you should also call `SetActive(false)`. This will deactivate the `GameObject`, and remove it from play, while letting it idle in the background until it's `Destroy()` method completes.

```
public class DestroyScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject player;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collision otherObj)
    {
        if (otherObj.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            player.SetActive(false);
            Destroy(player);
        }
    }
}
```

#### [Using `DestroyImmediate()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DestroyImmediate.html)

If you just want to immediately `Destroy()` a `GameObject`, call `DestroyImmediate()`, instead. Be advised: `DestroyImmediate()` is extremely unsafe. It is advised that this method is used *sparingly*, and only for *editor* tasks; I typically use an `#if UNITY_EDITOR` to ensure that an actual build still uses `Destroy()`, instead.

```
public class DestroyScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject player;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collision otherObj)
    {
        if (otherObj.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            #if UNITY_EDITOR
            DestroyImmediate(player);
            #else
            Destroy(player);
            #endif
        }
    }
}
```

It is ***very important*** to note the *overload* for `DestroyImmediate()`; while you provide an `Object`, much like `Destroy()`, you can also provide a `bool` to permit *asset deletion*. This `bool` defaults to `false`, but it is important to know that the functionality there can *permanently delete* assets.

```
public class DestroyScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject player;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collision otherObj)
    {
        if (otherObj.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            // I am now permitting permanent asset deletion. 
            // This can be real bad, mmkay?
            #if UNITY_EDITOR
            DestroyImmediate(player, true);
            #else
            Destroy(player);
            #endif
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any source on why the DestroyImmediate is unsafe? I mean I'll take your word for it and just try not to use it but it'd be nice to know why it's unsafe too.

Comment: @John Hamilton, only speculation, but I believe it circumnavigates cleanup (it was mentioned that Destroy() is slower as it makes sure each component is destroyed, too). There is also the fact that you can permanently delete assets. If you send in a reference to a game object in your assets (I.e. a prefab), and set the Boolean flag to true, it will *delete* the prefab. It also states that it is unsafe in the official documentation I linked.

Comment: This issue looks a bit funny to me. Even though `Destroy` does defer actual destruction, [the docs say it waits only until the end of a given frame's updates, before rendering for that frame](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html). I've never observed a lag like the one described in the question, so I wonder whether there might be something else going on here - say one of a dozen common errors in setting up physics so the collision isn't detected & `OnTriggerEnter` called until later than expected.

Comment: @DMGregory, all I could put it down to was user configuration error, but it does seem odd.

Comment: this solution works for me! thanks so much!!!