# Why does component.GetComponent<Rigidbody>() return "null", when a rigid body is NOT attached?

Tags: unity

In the following code, when `T` is `Rigidbody`, calling `componentToLookIn.GetComponent<T>()` returns `"null"` when there is no rigidbody attached, instead of simply `null`:

```
public static class ComponentExtensions
{
    public static bool TryFindComponent<T>(this Component componentToLookIn, out T componentToLookFor)
    {
        componentToLookFor = componentToLookIn.GetComponent<T>();          
        return componentToLookFor != null;
    }
}
```

Here is the debug window:

[image]

As a result, `componentToLookFor != null` ends up being `true`, which is obviously not what I want.

When I invoke `componentToLookIn.GetComponent<T>()` where `T` is **NOT** `Rigidbody`, `null` is returned as expected when there is no component of type `T` found.

What is so special about components of the `Rigidbody` type that `GetComponent<Rigidbody>()` behaves differently?

**EDIT:**

For contrast, here is the debug window when `GetComponent<BoxCollider>()` is invoked on a game object that does not have any component of the type `BoxCollider`:
[image]

As you can see, the `value` of `childComponent` is simply `null`, not `"null"`. `componentToLookFor != null` therefore returns `false`.

Comment: If it is a string it would say so in the type, no? Are you sure you aren't calling this method more often and are looking at the wrong call?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an Assert.IsNull test pass when the value is reported as <null>?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/115716/how-to-make-an-assert-isnull-test-pass-when-the-value-is-reported-as-null)

Comment: @Sidar I am 100% certain that I am looking at the correct call. I have updated my question to include more details.

Comment: Every time you try to `GetComponent<T>()` on a game object that doesn't have that `T` component, Unity return that pseudo-null indicated by `"null"`, as suggested by Tyyppi_77. Can you post the code that calls the extension method in the case of the rigidbody and the boxcollider?

Comment: Did the object never have this component attached, or was it attached then destroyed?

Comment: @DMGregory AFAIK it doesn't matter if the component isn't attached, or if it was and it's destroyed, in both cases the base value becomes `"null"` (ofc in the first case is  `"null"` as soon as `GetComponent` is executed) before the next `Update()` is called (I just tested it quickly to be sure).

Comment: @DMGregory It was never attached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens only when running in the Unity editor, and only with certain built-in component types.

In a release build, `GetComponent<T>()` always returns `null` if the GameObject does not have a component of type `T` attached.

When running inside the Unity Editor, `GetComponent<Rigidbody>()` instead returns a Rigidbody component that's been marked as a "stub" - an empty reference that perhaps the developer forgot to wire-up in the inspector. (It's not the string "null", that's just how it's configured to print when represented as text)

For these, Unity's overridden `==` operator for types deriving from `UnityEngine.Object` will return `true` when comparing to `null` (similar to what happens if you hold onto a reference to a component after it/its GameObject has been destroyed).

But the fact that it's *not* really null lets Unity offer more descriptive error messages, like...

- "Unassigned Reference Exception" (Inspector field not populated)
- "Missing Component Exception" (GetComponent<> with no matching component attached)
- "Missing Reference Exception" (Component has been destroyed)

---

So, if Unity's `==` is overridden to compare as equal to `null` in this case, why doesn't your null check work?

Because your generic method doesn't know that `T` is a `Component`, so it doesn't know to apply Unity's overridden operator.

To solve this and get consistent null detection between Editor and builds, you can add a `where T : Component` type constraint to your method, or cast your reference to a Unity type like a component first, then do your comparison with that.

Comment: Thank you for your very informative answer! I suppose another alternative is to change my ``return`` statement to ``return !childComponent.Equals(null);``?